# Switch between searchable from settings

Tags: android, search, toolbar, searchview

I have a `searchView` in Toolbar. When I tap on search, standard keyboard is displayed. But I want, if I set in settings numeric keyboard, and then tap on search, to see numeric keyboard.

Things like `searchView.setInputType(...)` or `setInputType(searchView,...)` are not working. One thing is working and that is set `inputType="number"` in `searchable.xml`. But I need two searchables and switch between them programmatically.

Is it possible? Or is there a better solution?